# Multiple Uploads to website from multiple="multiple"

Tags: php

i need your help. What I want is to upload multiple images at the same time using a form. I'm working on a admin panel that is connected to the website. But my problem is that I can't add multiple images to the database.
Here is the screenshot to my database -

> http://gyazo.com/c6952fb8c27a6cbaf48d2b571957fc4f

Comment: Where's your code to handle it?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/k6aW3dRb

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this -

```
    $fdata = $_FILES['img'];
    $uploads_dir = '/upload';
    for($i = 0; $i < count($fdata['name']); ++$i)
    {
        $name = $fdata['name'][$i];
        $temp_name = $fdata['tmp_name'][$i];
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$uploads_dir"."$name");
    }
```

Comment: Put your insert query in for loop sothat all the corresponding images will store in database.

Comment: Don't see the point of creating an extra copy of the $_FILES['img'] and only using it for a count. Why not just use `count($_FILES['img'])` ?

Comment: @DarkBee - yes ofcourse we can use in count() function but we can also use $fdata inside for loop.

Comment: i add 5 images and he add 5 camps whit description, name ... less the name the image, but i want like this http://gyazo.com/d0ca76e4f349d4f1dfe8015b2e848949

Comment: I have reviewed your code to insert data. You have used $pic variable for images, its now changed to $name. So please use $name for image name instead of $pic

Comment: i change de code, but he dont show all images, the images that i uploaded, like this http://gyazo.com/4e9802cafec267a7ae994a80f5766af1, i add 7 images and he show 3